# Uploaded War or Tar information is not printing on Jenkins console after upgrading to Gradle 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, gradle, build

I have updated `gradle` from `4.6` to `6.1`, now the problem is I cant see any information printed on jenkins console upon running `publishBootJavaPublicationToMavenRepository` task.

Before after this task use to see something like `Upload: http://nexusblabla.war`
but now nothing is printing with this task.

Comment: We ran into some possibly related issues during our recent upgrade from 3.4.1 to 6.0.1. I'm not sure, but I was under the impression that they changed some of the stdout capturing under the hood. It's possible that something which was originally piped to stdout is now only written to the logger. The messaging architecture that they use is still confusing to me, so I've had a tough time debugging these things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

If you simply would like to get back the log messages for uploaded files, then you have to use **Gradle’s `--info` command line option**. To stay with your example:

```
gradle --info publishBootJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
```

### Some Background

I don’t know why but obviously the log level for these messages has changed from `LIFECYLCE` to `INFO` with Gradle 4.10. You can see the difference with the `--debug` option when publishing:

- with Gradle 4.9 you get:

```
11:44:55.666 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader] Upload http://127.0.0.1:8000/com/example/foo/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0.zip
```

- with Gradle 4.10.3 you get:

```
11:55:44.666 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.LoggingMavenTransferListener] Uploading: com/example/foo/3.0.0/foo-3.0.0.zip to repository remote at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Unfortunately, this change does neither seem to be mentioned in the release notes nor any issue/commit – or at least I couldn’t find any such mentions. For completeness’ sake, here are all release notes entries for Gradle versions newer than 4.6 that are related to console logging:

- https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/release-notes.html#logs-grouped-by-task-for-non-interactive-executions
- https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/release-notes.html#changes-to-plain-console-behavior
- https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/release-notes.html#rich-console-improvements-on-windows
- https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/release-notes.html#rich-console-output-on-linux-aarch64-machines